# Making a copy of the current class using new

Tags: c++, pointers

How Can I make a copy of the current class using new?
I have tried

```
Sample* pointerToSample = new this;
```

Can someone explain how I can do that please?

Comment: `new auto(*this)` should do the trick.

Comment: @melpomene I want to make a copy. Sorry for misunderstanding, I updated my question

Comment: You have to explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a copy constructor, a quick search gave this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm